# FlowRouter.getParam errors on server in a Method

Tags: meteor

I'm a little confused by this error on the server. **Exception while invoking method 'slingshotUploadFile' TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getParam'** The error appears to be related to var `id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');` however when I console.log(id) it prints the correct id. 
Is `FlowRouter.getParam('id');` not suppose to be used in a method?

```
Meteor.methods({
  slingshotUploadFile: function( url ) {
    check(url, String);
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

    try {
      Files.insert({
        url: url,
        userId: id,
        added: new Date() 
      });
    } catch( exception ) {
      return exception;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The server has no info regarding your route. I suppose that you are logging it on the client. Simply send it as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can not use FlowRouter.getParams on server-side, you should pass in the parameters you got from client-side.